# erro com função em javascript

Tags: javascript

Galera tenho e seguinte código em javascript:

```
<script>
$('.valores,#qtd,#qtd_bo').mask('00.000.000,00', {
    reverse: true
});
</script>
```

Ele e um plugin de mascara, e funciona perfeitamente. Porém meu phpStorm esta marcando o `$` com o seguinte erro : unresolved function or method $()

Alguém sabe o que está errado?

Comment: Nada, ele não deve ter reconhecido o jquery é apenas um warning.

Comment: Tens o jQuery carregado na página?

Comment: o jQuery carrega em uma pagina separada, esta página e incluída dentro da principal com PHP. Notei que se eu usar o //noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction ele não verifica o warning, isso esta correto? eu tem alguma forma melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: Talvez te ajude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616683/phpstorm-unresolved-function-or-method.

Answer (score 1):

Nunca usei o phpStorm, mas pelo que entendi, se estiver funcionando OK o problema tá só no editor que acha que $ nunca foi declarado ou iniciado.